# Jenkins Config for Protractor

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I have been trying to figure out to setup Jenkins to run Protractor test,

1. start selenium server
2. running protractor test
3. stopping selenium server

I can't any proper tutorial or guide on to configure all of this within Jenkins.
A bit of help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd delegate as much responsibility as possible to `grunt`.

We've personally configured `Bamboo CI server` to run daily builds and remote tests at BrowserStack by simply executing the grunt task. Hope you can apply the following to `jenkins` as well. The following grunt tasks are required to be configured:

```
protractor: {
    options: {
        keepAlive: true,
        noColor: false
    },
    remote: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/e2e/config/remote.conf.js"
        }
    },
    local: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/e2e/config/local.conf.js"
        }
    }
},

protractor_webdriver: {
    options: {
        keepAlive: false
    },
    all: {

    }
},

browserstackTunnel: {
    options: {
        accessKey: browserstackKey  // your key here
    },
    development: {
        options: {
            port: 9001,
            force: true
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we have this `e2e:remote` task configured that does 3 things:

- starts local selenium server (and shuts down after)
- opens up browserstack tunnel
- runs `protractor` tests remotely on browserstack

Here is the task itself:

```
grunt.registerTask('e2e:remote', 'Runs end-to-end tests on browserstack', function () {
    var tasks = [
        'connect:test',
        'browserstackTunnel',
        'protractor:remote'
    ];

    grunt.option('force', true);
    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use Grunt (we do this at my work) you should be able to just do it via Jenkins via the command line parameters. Jenkins can make command line calls in the same way you would start your tests yourself from the command line.

When you start the Protractor tests you can have it configured so that it automatically starts a local selenium server. Or you could even just keep the selenium server running or have it called to start and stop explicitly from Jenkins.

In your task config you can set the calls in the Build > Execute Shell section as shown in this link http://edepree.com/2014/04/10/simple-grunt-setup-for-jenkins.html